# NUnit testcase generation: how to create sub-folders (hierarchy)?

Tags: c#, nunit, testcasesource

I am generating NUnit testcases based on the file names.

The directory looks like this:

```
Customer
    CustomerTestCase1.xml
    CustomerTestCase2.xml

Account
    AccountTestCase1.xml
    AccountTestCase2.xml
```

I am using TestCaseSource:

```
    string[] list = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)

    foreach (string file in list)
    {
        yield return new TestCaseData(file)
    }
```

How do I introduce hierarchy into the generated testcases? I need them to be organized in groups according to folder structure, so I could tick "Account" and all the account testcases would be selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Charlie Poole @ NUnit-Discuss

Hi Andrey,

If that structure is dynamic, then there is little you can do. However,
if the structure does not change, then you can simply code multiple
fixtures, with tests that take data from different sources.

So you might have a Customer fixture, pulling test data from some
particular source or sources, and an Account fixture pulling its data
from other sources.

Put the common code for these fixtures into a base class so that
you don't have to repeat the logic. In fact, it should be easy to
refactor directly from what you have to use of a base class and
then to create separate leaf classes for the tests you want to
select separately.

Charlie

http://groups.google.com/group/nunit-discuss/browse_thread/thread/543102e801511c41